# How to optimize database query and reduce number of request on data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a webpage where 1000's of records i am getting from the database. but page takes too much time to load and even safari browser throws a warning that webpage is taking too much memory. Now i can decrease the num of data but requests can be reduced what are the ways to reduce number of requests. 
if i use lazy loading queries that will webpage speed increase? because my webpage contains a lot of videos urls, google drive urls and documents may be the interpreter go to that links and check and come back to the application how i can do it in 1 request

This is my data is showing

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAseV.jpg

```
$productsFeatured = Product::select('products.low_emitting_material_prerequisite_file',
            'manufacturers.phone','manufacturers.address','manufacturers.linkedin_url','manufacturers.city','manufacturers.state', 
            'products.specs_file','products.bim_file_url','products.specs_file_url','products.low_emitting_material_credit_file', 
            'products.id', 'products.name', 'products.logo','products.video_file', 'products.manufacturer_id',
            'products.division_id', 'products.section_id','products.datasheet_file', 'products.website', 'divisions.name as division_name', 'divisions.code as division_code',
            'sections.name as section_name', 'sections.code'   
             )
                    ->whereIn('products.status', ['active']);

                    if($request->chps_approved && in_array('63', $request->chps_approved)){
                        $productsFeatured->where(function ($query) {
                            $query->where('products.low_emitting_material_prerequisite_file', '!=', '');
                        });
                    }

                    $productsFeatured->leftJoin('products_selected_leeds', 'products.id', '=', 'products_selected_leeds.product_id')
                    ->leftJoin('sections', 'products.section_id', '=', 'sections.id')
                    ->leftJoin('divisions', 'products.division_id', '=', 'divisions.id');
                    if($request->division_code){

                        $productsFeatured->where('products.division_id', '=', $request->division_code);

                        $data['divisionn_code'] = $request->division_code;
                    }
                 else{

                    $productsFeatured->where('products.division_id', '=', '1');
                    $data['divisionn_code'] = 1;
                    }
                    $productsFeatured->join('manufacturers', 'products.manufacturer_id', '=', 'manufacturers.id')
                    ->join('users', 'manufacturers.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                    ->orderBy('divisions.code', 'asc')
                    ->orderBy('sections.code', 'asc')
                    ->groupBy('products.id');
                    if($request->ajax()){
                        if($request->manufacturer){
                        $productsFeatured->whereIn('products.manufacturer_id', $request->manufacturer);
                        }
                        if($request->searchTxt){
                        $search_text = $request->searchTxt;

                        $productsFeatured->where(function ($query) use ($search_text) {
                        $query->orWhere('manufacturers.name', 'like', '%' . $search_text . '%');
                        $query->orWhere('sections.name', 'like', '%' . $search_text . '%');
                        $query->orWhere('products.name', 'like', '%' . $search_text . '%');
                        $query->orWhere('sections.name', 'like', '%' . $search_text . '%');
                        $query->orWhere('sections.code', 'like', '%' . $search_text . '%');
                        });
                        }
                        if($request->leedv4){

                        $where_in = $request->leedv4;

                        $query = DB::table('Products_selected_leeds')
                        ->select('product_id')
                        ->whereIn('leed_id',$where_in)
                        ->get();

                        $toCollection = collect($query);

                        $arrayOfIds = $toCollection->pluck('product_id')->toArray();

                        $productsFeatured->whereIn('products.id', $arrayOfIds);


                        }

                        if($request->website){

                            $productsFeatured->where('website','like', '%www%');
                        }  
                         if($request->video_file){

                            $productsFeatured->where('products.video_file','like', '%www%');

                        }if($request->bim_file_url){

                            $productsFeatured->whereNotNull('bim_file_url');

                        }if($request->specs_file){

                            $productsFeatured->where('bim_file_url','like', '%www%');

                        }
                        if($request->featured_products){
                            $featured = $request->featured_products;
                            $productsFeatured->where(function ($query) use ($featured) {
                                $query->orWhere('products.featured',$featured);
                                $query->orWhere('manufacturers.featured',$featured);


                                });

                        }
                        $productsFeatured = $productsFeatured->orderBy('manufacturers.name', 'ASC')->get();

                        }else{
                        $productsFeatured = $productsFeatured->orderBy('manufacturers.name', 'ASC')->get();

                        }
```

Can i do something like at 1st records are shown to the size of screen and when user user scroll down then query runs again from and get records to the screen size

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given us enough information to help you very well. Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952) paying special attention to the section on query performance, then edit your question to give more details.

That being said, it's this part of your query that's likely making your query slow.

```
                    $query->orWhere('manufacturers.name', 'like', '%' . $search_text . '%');
                    $query->orWhere('sections.name', 'like', '%' . $search_text . '%');
                    $query->orWhere('products.name', 'like', '%' . $search_text . '%');
                    $query->orWhere('sections.name', 'like', '%' . $search_text . '%');
                    $query->orWhere('sections.code', 'like', '%' . $search_text . '%');
```

MySQL handles this, an OR cascade of `'column LIKE '%search-term%'` very slowly indeed.

You *may* be able to speed it up with appropriate indexing. But you probably should investigate using [FULLTEXT search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should use pagination to split the data over several pages. Here is an example from a [tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-paginate-data-with-php--net-2928) that could get you started.

There is also some [example code](http://makerspacekanpur.com/simple-pagination-php-mysql/) here that could help.

As far as query performance is concerned, take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32162456/2570277) that could give you pointers on how to write your query.